# Contiguous subarray of floating numbers sums to integer algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, floating-point, dynamic-programming, divide-and-conquer

Suppose we have an array A of size n, there are n unsorted floating point numbers. We want to find a contiguous subarray B such that B sums to an integer. Suppose we can use floor function at cost of O(1). Note that we need to return B if such B exists.
My idea:

```
rsum = running sum of A(i.e. rsum[i]=A[1]+A[2]+...+A[i])
for i from 1 to n:
   for j from i to n:
      e = rsum[j]-rsum[i]+A[i]
      if e==floor(e)
         return A[i....j]
return "no such subarray"
```

This is an O(n^2) algorithm, is there a way to do that in o(n^2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we ignore floating point calculation errors, then we can put **fractional** parts of running sums into a map and check whether the same fraction exists twice - (close to) O(n) approach.

Considering precision issues, we can sort fractions (or put them into sorted container like RB tree) and get the smallest difference - O(nlogn) approach

Comment: A map is not properly O(1) insertion time, and so is not overall O(n) for inserting all the elements and checking for a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I know, but O(1) is typical time and it is usually used for rough estimation